# Best way to convert string to integer in Python

Tags: python

I have a spreadsheet with text values like `A067,A002,A104`. What is most efficient way to do this? Right now I am doing the following:

```
str = 'A067'
str = str.replace('A','')
n = int(str)
print n
```

Comment: Will the letter always be an A? Will the format always be identical, single letter followed by 3 digits?

Comment: What are the patterns? When do you feel a valid integer can be extracted? Does `Foo 42 Bar 81` contain one or two or no integers?

Comment: I can't be sure if the letter will always be `A`. As well I can't be sure that it will always be 3 digits but my guess is that it will based on the data that I have.

Comment: Could you update your question with more examples? And by efficient, you mean fastest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only non-number part of the input will be the first letter, the fastest way will probably be to slice the string:

```py
s = 'A067'
n = int(s[1:])
print n
```

If you believe that you will find more than one number per string though, the above regex answers will most likely be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data, the following might be suitable:

```
import string

print int('A067'.strip(string.ascii_letters))
```

Python's [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) command takes a list of characters to be removed from the start and end of a string. By passing [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=ascii_upper#string.ascii_letters), it removes any preceding and trailing letters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to find numbers.

```
import re

s = 'A067'
s = re.findall(r'\d+', s) # This will find all numbers in the string
n = int(s[0]) # This will get the first number. Note: If no numbers will throw exception. A simple check can avoid this
print n
```

Here's some example output of findall with different strings

```
>>> a = re.findall(r'\d+', 'A067')
>>> a
['067']
>>> a = re.findall(r'\d+', 'A067 B67')
>>> a
['067', '67']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method of regex from re module.

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(?P<numbers>.*?\d+")
matcher  = regex.search(line)
if matcher:
    numbers = int(matcher.groupdict()["numbers"] #this will give you the numbers from the captured group
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

str = 'A067'
print (int(str.strip(string.ascii_letters)))
```